# Print machine name in script

Tags: 7

I want to include a tracking script in my Drupal website and inside the script I want to include things like, title of page, description etc. In other words, I need to include the machine names inside the script.

But how can I do that. I need to change the %TEXT% to %MACHINE_NAME%.
The script is here:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Event",
"location": {
"@type": "Place",
"name": "%company-name%",
"logo": "%logo-url%",
"alternateName": "Universe Science Park",
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"streetAddress": "%address%",
"postalCode": "%postalcode%",
"addressLocality": "%city%",
"addressRegion": "%region%",
"addressCountry": "%country%"
}
},
"name": "%event-title%",
"description": "%event-descriptions%",
"startDate": "%startdate-and-time%",
"endDate": "%enddate-and-time%",
"image": [
"https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
"https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
"https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
],
"inLanguage": "%language%"
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use the Schema Metatag module () to output LD+ Json, and it will allow for using tokens to create the values you want.

Comment: @Jaypan
Found a solution. Read my comment below

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.
If somebody ever comes across same problem here is how you can manage it.

1. Download the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/tracking_code
2. After installing and activating go to Structure -> Tracking Code Snippets
3. Add tracking code
4. Here you can use tokens and add machine names

This is very simple and helped me alot!

I hope this will help you too. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to put together a new custom module.

At first your only going to need a few files:

- modules/custom/tracking/

  - js/

    - tracking.js
  - tracking.info.yml
  - tracking.libraries.yml

Define a new library for your javascript to live in, and add dependencies for `core/jquery` and `core/drupalSettings`. You can then create the file and follow the Javascript API to implement access to `drupal.settings` to get some of these items from Drupal directly.

Your other variables can be derived by JS or you can write your own PHP in the future if you need to send a new setting and expose it to the library. At this point your enabled to do whatever you would like to do.

**Sources:**

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview